# influxdb python: 404 page not found

Tags: python, influxdb

I am trying to use the influxdb-python lib which I found [here](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python). But I cant even get the tutorial programm to work.

When I run the following example code:

```
$ python

>>> from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

>>> json_body = [
    {
        "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
        "tags": {
            "host": "server01",
            "region": "us-west"
        },
        "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "value": 0.64
        }
    }
]

>>> client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example')

>>> client.create_database('example')
```

I get this error message with the last line:

```
>>> client.create_database('example')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 318, in create_database
    status_code=201
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 124, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientError: 404: 404 page not found
```

My installed version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ influx
Visit https://enterprise.influxdata.com to register for updates, InfluxDB server management, and monitoring.
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 0.9.6.1
InfluxDB shell 0.9.6.1
```

It would be really nice if somebody can point me to my probleme here.

**UPDATE**

Maybe this is helpful. I am on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Jessie and installed influxdb with this tuturial [link](http://padcom13.blogspot.co.at/2015/12/influxdb-telegraf-and-grafana-on.html)

**UPDATE 2**

if I run `curl http://localhost:8086` I also get 404 page not found. On the Port 8083 i get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Influxdb running on a Raspberry Pi2.

`InfluxDB shell 0.12.1` is the version I have. You are running 0.9.6.1 which could be outdated, but nevertheless still be the latest one available in the repo you use.

Your ports seem correct, a quick netstat shows:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8083                 :::*                    LISTEN      17740/influxd   
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN      17740/influxd   
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      17740/influxd
```

To test it, I used the same example script as you did, with a slight change:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
from datetime import datetime

from influxdb import InfluxDBClient


query = 'select value from wetter;'
client = InfluxDBClient(host='127.0.0.1', database='wetter')
print(client)

current_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
json_body = [
    {
        "measurement": "temperature",
        "tags": {
            "host": "192.168.0.82",
            "location": "room"
        },
        "time": current_time,
        "fields": {
            "value": random.random()
        }
    }
]
print(json_body)

client.write_points(json_body)
```

I then start the script with `while true; do ./influxdb-test.py; sleep 2; done` which will insert a new entry every 2 seconds.

```
> select * from temperature

1462865736000000000 192.168.0.82    room    0.116745414817
1462866059000000000 192.168.0.82    room    0.576278097718
1462866062000000000 192.168.0.82    room    0.731955354635
1462866065000000000 192.168.0.82    room    0.536106447983
1462866068000000000 192.168.0.82    room    0.965246396917
1462866070000000000 192.168.0.82    room    0.785592521739
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't post a comment since I don't have the reputation.

I found the same issue with a raspberry PI and v0.12.2. If you go to https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.12/guides/writing_data/ there is this command

curl -G http://localhost:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"

It worked for me.

**UPDATE 1**

I don't think you've installed the Python InfluxDB driver correctly.  Follow the steps on the [InfluxDB-Python](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/include-readme.html#id2) page.  Specifically be sure to run the following commands as sudo.

pip install influxdb

pip install --upgrade influxdb

Comment: thank you, I already use this workaround but I am looking for an answer for my problem with the influxdb-python lib

Comment: Testing the tutorial with the download 0.12.2 tar.gz (https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb-0.12.2-1_linux_armhf.tar.gz) worked on a 64 bit Linux VM but not on the raspberry PI.

Comment: Does interacting with InfluxDB on a Rasberry Pi through the [InfluxDB CLI](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.12/tools/shell) also have similar issues? I'm wondering if this is an general ARM InfluxDB issue or specific the python client.

Comment: I haven't try the InfluxDB CLI.   I'm pretty certain the Python driver is up to date since I tried it with a 64-bit Linux virtual machine I spun up on AWS.    According to the [Influx documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.12/administration/logs/) it says the log files are located at /var/log/influxdb/.  @MarkB, can you look at  the logs and see what they show?

Comment: Thanks UPDATE 1 fixed my issue on a RPi3!