# InfluxDB Python Connection

Tags: python, influxdb

Python Version - 2.7
InfluxDB Version - 1.5.0

I'm a newbie, and I am trying to connect my InfluxDB database with Python so I can write code for future projects.

I tested out the example program from this [link](http://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/include-readme.html). (Direct code below)

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

json_body = [
{
    "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
    "tags": {
        "host": "server01",
        "region": "us-west"
    },
    "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
    "fields": {
        "value": 0.64
    }
  }
]

client = InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example')

client.create_database('example')

client.write_points(json_body)

result = client.query('select value from cpu_load_short;')

print("Result: {0}".format(result))
```

Upon running the program, I am receiving this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "influxentryexample.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.create_database('example')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 318, in create_database
    status_code=201
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 124, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientError: 404: 404 page not found
```

Comment: It seems to be that you don't install correctly influx db driver to python, check out this, please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846975/influxdb-python-404-page-not-found/36952335#36952335

Answer (score 2):

if you install influxdb without changing its config file, 
you could login without using username and password, so just type:

```
client = influxdb.InfluxDBClient(host='localhost', port=8086)
```

and then you will establish the connection between python and influxdb 
but in this way, you did not assign which database you want to insert data
before `write_points(jsonbody)`.
You need to use `client.create_database()` and `client.switch_database()` like:

```
client.create_database('example')
client.switch_database('example')
```

But as the learner (so was I) you'd better learn how to use restful API request to do some work.It will help us to understand how influxdb works